# ImageResizer out of memory error in a console application

Tags: imageresizer

I wrote some code to resize a large number of images using ImageResizer.

```
foreach(DataRow item in dst.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     string dir = @"C:\Media\ImageCollection\" + item[image];

     string outputDir = @"D:\ImageExport\" + item[filename].ToString().SubString(0, 5);

     if (!Directory.Exists(outputDir))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);

     if (Convert.ToInt32(item["width"]) > Convert.ToInt32(item["height"]))
          ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(dir, outputDir + @"\" + item["image"] + ".jpg", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("?maxwidth=500&format=jpg&quality=96"), true);
     else
          ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(dir, outputDir + @"\" + item["image"] + ".jpg", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("?maxheight=500&format=jpg&quality=96"), true);
}
```

The code randomly throw the exception **Out of Memory in the System.Drawning.Image** on one of the ImageResizer.ImageBuilder call.

I am wondering if I am missing something in the AppConfig file.

```
<configSections>
     <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer"  requirePermission="false"  />
</configSections>  

<resizer>
     <plugins>
          <remove name="SizeLimiting" />
          <add name="PdfRenderer" downloadNativeDependencies="false" />
     </plugins>
</resizer>
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you posted, you are trying to use a directory path (@"C:\Media\ImageCollection") as the input image filename. ImageResizer works on 1 image at a time; you need to provide the input image filename instead.

OutOfMemoryException is a generic error message thrown by the Microsoft API whenever something goes wrong; it doesn't always mean there's no memory available.

Comment: I change the code a bit, I am passing the input image to the ImageResizer  build call, the error always occurs after a random amount of images are process.

Comment: Try calling GC.Collect() and Thread.Sleep(10) every iteration. It's possible you're fragmenting the memory space so quickly that allocations start to fail.

Comment: It seems the server was using too many resources and restart was all I needed to do. I will add your recommendations, that should definitely keep that error from happening again.